# I do not want to show the port in clickUri

Tags: coveo

Good day,

I do not want to show the port of the link in COVEO.

Example: 
In this moment:
https://test.testpage.com:443/places/cub

What I want:
https://test.testpage.com/places/cub

Is any configuration that I can modify to reach this?

Thank you.

Comment: Not about Sitecore.  This is about Coveo.

Comment: so that configuration is the side of sitecore?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are referring clickable uri value. Coveo uses targethostname or hostname values that are set on the site definition. https://docs.coveo.com/en/2545/coveo-for-sitecore-v5/understanding-how-the-clickableuri-value-is-computed

Comment: Thanks for this answer rejeev. This is exactly the right response for this question!